# Caps Lock behavior under Sway / Wayland

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, wayland, sway, capslock

Under X, I can make Caps Lock behave as Esc when pressed briefly, but as Ctrl when held down with:

```
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape' -t 100
```

How can I replicate this behavior under Sway / Wayland?

Answer (score 8):

Put the following in your sway config:

```
input "type:keyboard" {
    xkb_options caps:ctrl_modifier
}
```

Source: https://github.com/swaywm/sway/wiki#keyboard-layout

UPDATE: the OP asks for "Caps lock is an Escape but is a Control when held".  Turns out there is a [simple program](https://github.com/oblitum/caps2esc) that does exactly that at libevdev level (so works with any display server, Wayland or not, and the sway config above is not needed).

A related discussion thread: https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/719

Comment: Thanks, this helps for making Caps Lock behave as Ctrl, but it only answers half the question. I also want Caps Lock to behave like Escape when it is pressed briefly. It could be that Sway just can't do this yet.

Comment: @Alexander updated my answer.  Sway doesn't do that but there is another tool that does exactly that.

Comment: You can use `type:keyboard` as `<identifier>`.